# JQuery Select2 drop down onchange option text color not changing

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have a drop down using `Select2` . I need to change the drop down option text color on `onchange`. What I did as follows:

```
$("#e1").change(function(){
   $(this).css('color', 'red');
});
```

But it is not working as expected.

Fiddle:[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/santhucool007/jEADR/2328/)

**Select2 version : 4.0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make use of the `.data('select2')`, populated on the element, like this:

```
$("#e1").select2();
$("#e1").change(function() {
    $("#e1").data('select2').selection.css('color', 'red');
});
```

Here's an [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jEADR/2352/)

Answer (score 1):

`select2` changes the html, you will no longer have a `select` with the `id` of `e1`. The element you will have instead will be a `div` with the `id` of `s2id_e1`.

It seems that:

> id => "s2id_" + id

Also, you will no longer have a `change` event, since your div will have no value. You need to use a `click` handler for the `select2-choice` elements of `s2id_e1`:

```
$("#e1").select2();
$("#s2id_e1 .select2-choice").click(function(){
   $(this).css('color', 'red');
});
```

Comment: is it possible to change on onchange()

Comment: No, change is triggered when, by user action the value is changed. Since you end up with a div, which will have no value, you will need to forget about change events.